# Plotting a mixed effects model with three fixed effects

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to find a way to visualize a mixed effects model for a project I am working on, but am unsure how to do this when using multiple fixed and random effects.

The project I am working on is an attempt to estimate the helpfulness of online reviews, based on several different factors. A sample of the data looks like this:

```
Participant    Product Type   Star Rating    Anonymous   Product  Helpfulness
1               Exp            Extr          Yes          12         8
1               Search         Extr          Yes          6          6 
1               Search         Mid           Yes          13         7
...
30              Exp            Mid           No           11         2
30              Exp            Mid           No           14         4
30              Search         Extr          No           9          5
```

The data is significantly longer than this (30 participants, who each saw roughly two dozen reviews, resulting in approx. 700 entries). Each participant sees a mix of products, product types, and star ratings, but all of the reviews they see will either be anonymous or not anonymous (no mix).

As a result, I tried to fit a maximal mixed model, with the following:

```
mixed(helpfulness ~ product_type * star_rating * anonymity 
    + (product_type * star_rating | participant) 
    + (star_rating * anonymity | product))
```

What I would like to do now is to find a way of visually representing the data, likely color-coding the 8 different "groups" (essentially, the different unique combinations of the 3 binary independent variables (2 types of products * 2 types of star ratings * 2 types of anonymity), to show how they relate to the helpfulness rating.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make notional data
df <- data.frame(participant = seq(1,30,1),
                 product_type = sample(x=c('Exp', 'Search'), size=30, replace=T),
                 star_rating = sample(x=c('Extr', 'Mid'), size=30, replace=T),
                 anonymous = sample(x=c('Yes', 'No'), size=30, replace=T),
                 product = rnorm(n=30, mean=10, sd=5),
                 helpfullness = rnorm(n=30, mean=5, sd=3))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x=participant, y=helpfullness, fill=product, color=anonymous)) +
  facet_grid(c('product_type', 'star_rating'))
```

This captures all six variables in your data. You can also work with `alpha` and other aesthetics to include the variables. Using `alpha` might be better if you do not want to use a `facet_grid`. If you include `alpha` as an aesthetic, I would recommend using `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`.

[image: plot]